# Why does Typescript require a explicit cast for this valid object?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Let's take the following simplified example, based on a mongodb generic service implementation in Typescript:

```js
type BaseDocument = {
  _id: string;
};

class MongoDbService<T extends BaseDocument> {
  find(where: Partial<T>) {
    // ...
  }

  findById(_id: string) {
    return this.find({ _id });
  }
}
```

*`BaseDocument` is the base class for database collections (e.g. `User` would extend `BaseDocument`)*

While Typescript correctly suggests `_id` as a valid property of the object passed to the `this.find` call, it then reports the object as invalid with the following error message:

```
Argument of type '{ _id: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<T>'.ts(2345)
```

Any idea of what is going on here? I can workaround it by explicitly casting the object to `<Partial<T>>` but I feel it shouldn't be necessary.

[image]

[image]

Comment: the `_id` property could be narrower than `string`, like `{_id: "x" | "y"}`, and then you're trying to pass an arbitrary `string` to something that only accepts `"x" | "y"`. See the linked q/a for more information.